# When using hashlib in Python, a different value returned when fetched from a database

Tags: python, sqlite, hashlib

I am using Python 3.5 and when I use hashlib.md5(), a different value is returned from a database than when a string is hashed outside.

The code I am using:

```
self.m = hashlib.md5()
self.m.update(self.password.encode('utf-8'))
self.passCheck = self.m.digest()
```

This process, when using 'user1pass' as a password returns:

```
b' \xa0\xdbS\xbc\x18\x81\xa7\xf79\xcd\x95kt\x009'
```

However, when I fetch from a database:

```
self.cur.execute("SELECT Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ?;", username)
    self.userFindings = self.cur.fetchall()
    self.userDetails = []
    for each in self.userFindings:
        self.userDetails.append(list(each))

    return self.userDetails
```

self.userDetails in this case looks like this:

```
[['user1', "b' \\xa0\\xdbS\\xbc\\x18\\x81\\xa7\\xf79\\xcd\\x95kt\\x009'"]]
```

Somehow in the process, the slashes have been doubled, meaning that they can not be compared properly. Anyone have any idea what caused this?

EDIT: Photo of output

[Output of self.passCheck and self.userDetails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqTNY.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you put `repr` of the hash string into the database, instead of the value itself.

Comment: @Anthon: the problem is in extra quotes that makes slashes literal: `"b' \xa0\xdbS\xbc\x18\x81\xa7\xf79\xcd\x95kt\x009'"`. (It took me some time to realize what's wrong, too.)

Comment: You inserted some backslashes (`\ `) while editing, not slashes (`/`). That should not be necessary. I would just assume the OP did copy and paste what was there on the screen.

Comment: Yeah I copied what was outputted from printing self.passcheck with 'userpass1' and then what was in self.userDetails

Answer (score 0):

I have now found that if I open up the list then the two hash values match. It appears to be a display error